# "In office" or "at office"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“At” or “in” the office?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9749/at-or-in-the-office)

I am a little confused about which preposition should be used here as in the title. I prefer to use *in office*. But how about the other one? Are both correct or not?

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use them more or less like this:

- "in office" = "having taken up their official position" (e.g. as an MP, president...)
- "in the office" = "present in the office"
- "at the office" = "in the office for the purpose of carrying out his duties"

Comment: I'd distinguish between "in the office" and "at the office" slightly differently. I'd use "at the office" in opposition to "at home" -- at his place of work, but maybe not necessarily physically in his office, while "in the office" means that he is physically present in his office.

Comment: Interesting to pick on 'in office' as valid - well done.  I can think of no parallel for 'at office' that would be valid.

Comment: Since the poster specifically mentioned "in/at office" without the article I thought I'd better clarify. Incidentally (I'm from the UK) I don't get the reading that Peter does with "at the office": to me it implies they're actually working at the office (whereas "at work" could imply e.g. they're out on the road).

Comment: It's somewhat tangential, but there is a chain of bar & grill restaurants in New Jersey called "The Office." The joke is that you can go there, call home, and say "Honey, I'll be staying late at The Office." I don't believe Americans would use "in" for this usage, although they would say "Honey, I'm in the office".